# Service provider exception on registering a user manager for a template user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP .NET Core and today I have stumbled across something. I have `User` class which inherits `IdentityUser` and adds some custom fields, such as first name, last name, etc...

The `User` class is further extended by other types of users, which only add one or two extra fields, at most. I have decided to take this route as it was unnecessary to repeat the same code in 4 places.

I have defined a `UserRepository` which implements an interface `IUserRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : User`. Whenever I try to access the `Index`, I get an exception like:

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[HM.models.users.Medic]' has been registered.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<T>(IServiceProvider provider)
HM.repositories.UserRepository<TEntity>..ctor(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string role) in UserRepository.cs
+
            _userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TEntity>>();
HM.repositories.MedicRepository..ctor(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in MedicRepository.cs
+
        public MedicRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(context, serviceProvider, _role) { }
HM.persistence.UnitOfWork..ctor(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider _serviceProvider) in UnitOfWork.cs
+
            Medics = new MedicRepository(_context, _serviceProvider);
app.Controllers.MedicController.Index() in MedicController.cs
+
            using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_context, _serviceProvider))
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Those are some code snippets:

`MedicController`:

```
 // GET: Medic
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_context,_serviceProvider))
        {
            return View(await unitOfWork.Medics.GetAll());
        }
    }
```

`UserRepository` and `IUserRepository`:

```
   public interface IUserRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : User
    {
        Task Add(TEntity user, string password);
        Task Remove(TEntity user);
        Task Update(TEntity user);
        Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll();
        Task<TEntity> GetById(string id);
        Task<bool> Any(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate);
    }

    public class UserRepository<TEntity> : IUserRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : User
    {
        private readonly string _role;
        private readonly UserManager<TEntity> _userManager;

        public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string role)
        {
            _role = role;
            _userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TEntity>>();
        }


        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll()
        {
            return await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(_role);
        }
    }
```

Finally, the medic:

```
[Table("Medic")]
public class Medic : User
{
    [DisplayName("Departments")]
    public ICollection<MedicDepartment> departments { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Diagnostics")]
    public ICollection<MedicDiagnostic> diagnostics { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    [DisplayName("Rank")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "The rank name must be between 3 and 30 characters long!")]
    public string rank { get; set; }
}
```

I have debugged the application: it will throw this exception at `_userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TEntity>>();` inside `UserRepository`. I don't understand why this hapens since 
I have clearly stated `where TEntity : User`.

Thanks!
P.S. I have removed some code and some emthods to make this post more redable.
P.S.S: The `MedicRepository` class extends `UserRepository` and calls `base` and contains, for now, nothing else. The `UnitOfWork` contains all the application repositories and calls `new` on each one of them inside its contructor.
P.S.S.S. I wanted to use templates for this repository in order to avoid casting inside controllers. It used to return 'User' related data.

Comment: would you share your class that is HM.models.users.Medic

Comment: I totally missed that one, it has been added now.

Comment: Look at this link https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7856

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have already done that. I have injected the proper UserManger and SignInManager of type User. This does not happen on Create, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was not enough to register a service for `UserManager<User>`, but I also had to register a `UserManager` for each type of user which inherited `User`.

First, I added those lines to `Startup.cs` inside `ConfigureServices`. This used `IdentityCore` instead `Identity`.

```
        services.AddIdentityCore<Medic>()                       //add the derived user type from custom user
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Medic, IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddDefaultUI();
```

Secondly, don't forget to add the managers. Same as before, in the same file and method, add:

```
   services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>, UserManager<User>>();     //the user manager for the base type of User
   services.AddScoped<UserManager<Medic>, UserManager<Medic>>();   //the user manager for Medics
```

Hope it helps!